# SQL - Multiple Selects with Case

Tags: sql

```
+--------+---------+----------+----------+-------+------------+------------+
| F Name | L Name  | Event ID | Group ID | Hours | Event Type | Event Name |
+--------+---------+----------+----------+-------+------------+------------+
| Bill   | Johnson |        1 |          | 3     | Event      | Indirect   |
| Janet  | Jackson |          |        1 | 1     | Group      |            |
| Bill   | Johnson |          |        1 | 1     | Group      |            |
| Chris  | Margot  |        2 |          | 1.5   | Event      | Direct     |
| Janet  | Jackson |          |        1 | 1     | Group      |            |
+--------+---------+----------+----------+-------+------------+------------+
```

I have a table like this. I need to calculate the sum of the hours column if the event type is NOT group and direct.

I then need to sum hours if the event type is group but only once per person per group id. (So Janet would have 1 hour for her group not 2 because they have the same group ID. I am getting unexpected results.

I know It will involve a self join. The table is called public.event_by_wkr event_by_wkr in the FROM part of the query. I see this as rather difficult but it may not be. If you need more information I will provide it.

Comment: Please update the question with the RDBMS you are using (mysql, sql server, oracle, etc). I don't believe this will be difficult, nor will it require a self join. It may also help if you can share, for this sample data, your desired results. That way we can walk back the logic for each person to the sample data and understand more clearly.

Comment: have you written any query already? show us

Comment: Please show expected result - which of Janet's records should choose?

Comment: So you need two distinct queries right?

Comment: If Janet have a record with 1 hour and other with 1.5 hour? What need to be the result?

Comment: The results I am looking for are simple. If the event is not a group then sum the hours if the name is direct.

For the group I need a sum of the hours but only once per group ID. Think about a teacher teaching a class. If the teacher spent 1 hour teaching 20 kids they spent 1 hour not 20 (1x20). I think this will be the difficult part. I can make the queries if I separate them but I have a query limit with ODBC so I need to combine as many queries as possible.